# instagram app-in browser image Can't upload

Tags: html, instagram, mobile-website

I'm sorry. Because I am using a translation machine, understanding may be difficult.
It is a web developer working in Japan.

If you do the following operation, a bug will cause a bug in the instagram.

1. Send the URL in 「direct」 in the instagram.
   (iPhone Application)
   (There is a form with  in the URL.)
   (LIKE http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/)
2. Click URL from the 「direct」 and the URL opens in app-in browser.
3. When uploading a file (image) with Form, the page will be reloaded and the entered file will be deleted.

   - You can upload the same URL in public browser without problems.
     We could not add multiple or accept = "image / *" attribute to .
     [File upload control not working in Facebook In-App Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000708/file-upload-control-not-working-in-facebook-in-app-browser)

It is an innovative function of my web application and I really want to fix it
Is not there any good way

Comment: I have the exact same issue with IOS and the instagram app

Comment: super annoying, i have this same issue. the web app works everywhere and in every other social app browser webview EXCEPT for instagrams...

Comment: Update: As far as i can tell there's no solution for this. I've submitted a bug report to instagram. I also independently tested giphy.com, tinypic.com, and even logged in to facebook in the instagram in-app browser and can confirm every single site that uses photo uploads refreshes in instagrams in-app browser. No photo uploads work in instagram, which sucks...